# Axios 400 Bad Request Cognito JWT generation in Node Js

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, axios, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create **Cognito** **JWtoken** via POST call with **axios** in Lambda function using node js , but i am getting error *400 bad request.* 
In parallel it is working fine in Postman.

Code :

```
 await axios.post('https://smartfactoryfabric-dev.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token', {
        grant_type: grantType, // This is the body part
        redirect_uri: redirectURI,
        client_id: clientid,
        code: 'fb06a2dd-XXXXXXXXX-f186c6302806'
    }, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authValue
        }
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response)
        });
```

Comment: What's the error message you get when you get bad request? Amazon Services is quite informative about errors. Have you checked that the body you send is filled as you expected before executing the request?

Comment: also you could compare this with the code that postman can generate for curl or request.

Comment: HI @RobertMoskal  i compare both Postman,Curl with Node js code testing locally, All are same, in request  headers & body.   Error message : 400 bad request

Comment: @NaorLevi Error :     data:Object {error: "invalid_request"} , error:"invalid_request"

Answer (score 4):

You need to URL encode the body of your request into a single string. You can use `querystring.stringify` to do this.

```
   let data = querystring.stringify({
        grant_type: 'grantType', 
        redirect_uri: 'redirectURI',
        client_id: 'clientid',
        code: 'fb06a2dd-XXXXXXXXX-f186c6302806'
    })

=> 'client_id=clientid&code=fb06a2dd-XXXXXXXXX-f186c6302806&grant_type=grantType&redirect_uri=redirectURI'
```

Then your request will look like this:

```
 await axios.post('https://smartfactoryfabric-dev.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token', 
    data, 
    {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authValue
        }
    })
```